# Best way to put text below icon image

Tags: css

I am trying to use Material Design Lite library.

What's the best way to put an icon in one of the tabs and have the tab text below it (keeping in mind best practices and scalability).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzAEQb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple header with fixed tabs. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
                mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active"><i class="material-icons">person</i><span class="MY-CLASS-2">TAB 1</span> </a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="fixed-tab-1">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-2">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-3">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**html**

```
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="caption">Tab</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhLk4/360/

Answer (score 0):

I can do it by structuring one of the divs like so:

```
<a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active MY-CLASS-1"><i class="material-icons">person</i><span class="MY-CLASS-2">Profile</span> </a>
```

And adding the following styles:

```
.MY-CLASS-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
}

.MY-CLASS-2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    font-size: smaller;
    left: 198px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKEQZr

How can I make this code better overall?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul,
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a span {
  background: url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/2255/cologne/32/user.png') no-repeat #ccc;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><span></span>aaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span></span>bbbb</a></li>
    <li><a href="">cccc</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span></span>dddd</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```